# How to populate a JLabel with blobs from MySQL tables

Tags: java, mysql, binary, blob

I have tried all the solutions they have offered at stackoverflow and some other websites on how to show a blob from MySQL in a JLabel (I'm using eclipse IDE not that it matters), but it has been of no use. I'm using the "sakila" default/standard/built-in database in MySQL. I'm trying to get the blob in the field "picture" in the staff table into a JLabel on a form. Nothing is working. I have racked my brains.

Comment: Made it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess the blob file was corrupted after all. I tried to insert a new blob in MySQL and was able to retrieve it just fine and put it into a JLable.